# Testing REDUX connected component mapDIspatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I just needed an advise on how to test redux connected component. Got stuck learning Jest and enzyme. I am not sure if I am doing the test right. can guys advise on whats the proper way to test the code App Component.

Mainly I want to test if the dispatch has been called inside the useEffect hooks.

Is it still necessary to test the component?

Please see the code below: appreciate if you can advise me the proper to test these component.

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React,{useEffect,useState} from "react"

import {Route, Redirect, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom"
import { connect } from "react-redux"

// Import Routes all
import { userRoutes, authRoutes } from "./routes/allRoutes"

// Import all middleware
import Authmiddleware from "./routes/middleware/Authmiddleware"
import NewAuthmiddleware from "./routes/middleware/newAuthmiddleware"
// layouts Format
import VerticalLayout from "./components/VerticalLayout/"
import HorizontalLayout from "./components/HorizontalLayout/"
import NonAuthLayout from "./components/NonAuthLayout"
import Login from '../src/pages/Authentication/Login'
import Dashboard from "../src/pages/Dashboard/index"


// Import scss
import "./assets/scss/theme.scss"
import './assets/scss/globalstyling/style.scss'

import {validateToken} from './store/auth/login/actions'
import { Provider } from "react-redux"

// @import "~react-image-gallery/styles/scss/image-gallery.scss";


const App = props => {

  useEffect(()=>{
    const token = localStorage.getItem('auth-token')
    if(token){
      props.validateToken(localStorage.getItem('auth-token'))
    }
  },[props.loginData.isAuthenticated])
  

  function getLayout() {
    let layoutCls = VerticalLayout
    switch (props.layout.layoutType) {
      case "horizontal":
        layoutCls = HorizontalLayout
        break
      default:
        layoutCls = VerticalLayout
        break
    }
    return layoutCls
  }

  const Layout = getLayout()
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          {/* <Route exact path="/login" name="login" component={Login}></Route>
          <Route path="/" component={Dashboard}></Route> */}
          {authRoutes.map((route, idx) => (
            <Authmiddleware
              path={route.path}
              layout={NonAuthLayout}
              component={route.component}
              tokenValidated = {props.loginData.isAuthenticated}
              key={idx}
              isAuthProtected={false}
            />
          ))}
          {userRoutes.map((route, idx) => (
            <Authmiddleware
              path={route.path}
              layout={Layout}
              component={route.component}
              key={idx}
              tokenValidated = {props.loginData.isAuthenticated}
              isAuthProtected={true}
              exact
            />
          ))}
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

App.propTypes = {
  layout: PropTypes.any
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {

  const {loginData} = state.Login

  return {
    layout: state.Layout,
    loginData    
  }
  // const {tokenValidated} = state.Login
  // const {layout} = state.Layout
  // return {tokenValidated,layout}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {validateToken})(App)
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of Unit Testing is test only the unit you want to test, in this case the 'App' component.

So Redux 'connect' function logic is not a part of this component.

So you have two options:

1. Mocking the 'connect' function, you may take a look here how to do so https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions)
2. Export the 'App' component without the 'connect' part. The Redux data is passing as props eventually so you can pass diffent props value in each test case.

And onther recommendation is moving the selector to a diffrent file , you may use it again :

```
// selectors from selectors.js file: 
export const layoutSelector = state =>  state.Layout;

export const loginDataSelector = state =>  state.Login.loginData;

// using selectors :

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  layoutSelector :layoutSelector 
  loginData : loginDataSelector 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Zordon appreciate. so does it mean that I don't have to test a if the app component will fire the dispatch action on its useEffect hook?

Comment: As I said  usually in unit tests you want to test the unit logic. So if the unit (the component) fires an event you should test if the event was fired but if the component should change by this event you should mock it (mock the Redux data state, the props that may change by it .You may have more than one case so it be good to mock each case and run a different test on it)

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do to simplify it is when the app mounted I will expect that there is an **auth-token** in localStorage

```
expect(window.localStorage.getItem('auth-token')).toBeTrue()
```